# Facebook PHP SDK and login button

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-4, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am developing a Web app with Laravel and using Facebook's PHP SDK.  I want to have Facebook's "Login" button appear on my homepage, but that apparently only comes with the JavaScript SDK.  How do I get Facebook's "Login" button when I'm using Facebook's PHP SDK to log users in?

Answer (score 0):

Add these three css files in your Web app.

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css

bootstrap.min.css

https://raw.github.com/noizwaves/bootstrap-social-buttons/v1.0.0/social-buttons.css

And then write this in your view.

```
<button class="btn btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> | Connect with Facebook</button><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

These buttons don't come just like that. In JS you must have use `facebook-login-button` that's the reason its coming there. The same button can not be used while using the PHP SDK.

In PHP you can create them yourself. Try this-

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
   $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

<?php if ($user): ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>   <!-- design these buttons -->
<?php else: ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

The code is self-explanatory I guess :)

Comment: Hi Sahil. Facebook is a popular, trusted application.  I very specifically want FB's login button so that my application can leverage Facebook's one billion users to become successful, not just a generic login button that anyone can make on an unknown, untrusted application.

Comment: @AndrewKoper Dont worry man. Just for information- most of the applications dont use the default login button beacuse its too small and may not fit their theme. Why is that a problem, dont worry. It will behave just like a fb login button, no difference at all. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the answer from Abdussami Tayyab and works fine

I got the latest from http://fontawesome.io/ (4.2.2) then created a /fonts and /css in top folder of website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style>
<?php include 'css/font-awesome.css'; ?>
<?php include 'css/font-awesome.min.css'; ?>
<?php include 'css/social-buttons.css'; ?>
</style>



</head>

<body>

<?php 

print "Hello world!"; 
?>

<button class="btn btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> | Connect with Facebook</button><br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and implemented the Javascript login and then used Firebug to get the styles and URLs to images.  I didn't bother to clean up the CSS so there is likely things that don't need to be here, feel free to clean it up some and re-post.  My sizing matches the 'like' and 'post' button's, not the original log-in button.

Two things not covered here: The button doesn't do anything.  Make it a link or use Javascript.  I included the link to the 'progress' graphic but didn't implement it either.

Link to facebook images (image names changed later):
https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yB/r/t4ZSL-NWK2R.png
https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yE/r/49Rx-CGUu94.gif

CSS:

```
.facebook_button{
    background: linear-gradient(#4c69ba,#3b55a0) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-color: #4c69ba;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #ff;
    font-family: "Helvetica neue";
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #354c8c;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    /*now inherited*/
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #354c8c;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 1.28;
    padding: none;
};
.facebook_button:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(#5b7bd5, #4864b1) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-color: #5874c3 #4961a8 #3b5998;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #607fd6 inset;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.facebook_login{
    border: 0 none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Helvetica neue";
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #354c8c;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    direction: ltr;
line-height: 1.28;
}

.outer{
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    font-family: "helvetica neue", helvetica,arial,"lucida grande",sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:11px;
    /*now inherited*/
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #354c8c;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 1.28;
}

.middle{
    border: medium none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "helvetica neue",helvetica,arial,"lucida grande",sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    font-size: 11px;
    /*inherited*/
}

.inner{
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: medium none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    direction: ltr;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="facebook_button">   
<table class="facebook_login">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="outer">
                <span class="middle">
                    <span class="inner">
                     <img src="library/img/facebook.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="outer">
                <span class="middle">
                    <span class="inner">
                     Log In
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```